# php IDE intellisense on class objects

Tags: php, intellisense

//I Have a code like this

```
class Docs{
    public $docName;
    public $files=array();
}
class Files{
    public $fileName;
}
$doc=new Docs;
$doc->files[0]=new Files;

// I have intellisense in this level
$doc->

//but there is no intellisense in next level 
$doc->files[0]->
```

//which IDE shoud I use ?
//I already test dreamweaver and zend Studio .

Comment: What you are trying to do @vandad

Comment: You have initialized $files as array and you are assigning it a files object

Comment: $doc->files[0]=new Files;

Comment: still no intellisense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PHP can be duck-typed, the types of object properties cannot be determined without explicit type declarations via [PHPDoc](http://www.phpdoc.org/) (if DreamWeaver supports it) or reflection performed by the IDE if the flow is clear enough (if the property was passed to the object by a constructor that uses scalar type hinting, etc...).

$doc->files could contain just about anything, so what can the IDE do?

In any case, I always recommend [PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) as a PHP IDE.